# Covering a rectangle of size $n\times1$ with dominos

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, integer-partitions

A rectangle of size $n\times1$ is given.

(a) In how many ways the rectangle can be covered with dominoes of size $1\times1$ and $2\times1$?

(b) In how many ways the rectangle can be covered with dominoes of size $1\times1$, $2\times1$, and $3\times1$?

(c) In how many ways the rectangle can be covered with dominoes of size $1\times1$, $2\times1$, $3\times1$, and $4\times1$?

(d) In how many ways the rectangle can be covered with dominoes of size $1\times1$ and $3\times1$?

For the sake of simplicity, I suggest denoting these numbers with $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$,  $D_n$, respectively.

---

*Solution for (a):*

It is obvious $A_1=1$ and $A_2=2$. Let's observe $n\times1$ rectangle, and its last domino (from one short side). It can be $1\times1$ and $2\times1$ domino. This means $A_n = A_{n-1} + A_{n-2}$. In other words, $A_n$ are Fibonacci numbers.

*(b), (c):*

It looks $B_n$ and $C_n$ are so called tribonacci and tetranacci numbers.

Comment: ... and the same method produces recurrence relations in the other cases.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Verifying $A_0$ is a little bit tricky, because it requires the non-intuitive understanding that a $0\times 1$ rectangle can be tiled in one way.  It might be easier to verify on $A_2$, as OP does.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Why is it non-intuitive? A tiling just means a set of tiles that completely fill the space without overlaps. When the space is of zero size, then there is exactly one tiling regardless of the tiles, since the empty set of tiles is the only one that works. Do you have an actual example where this reasoning is wrong?

Comment: @user21820 While it's 'obvious' once you know combinatorics, I think if you asked 'how many ways are there to tile a $2\times 1$ square? How many are there to tile a $1\times1$ square? Now how many are there to tile a $0\times 1$ square?', most people by far (including students) would say 'zero' to the last.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Heheh well I'd say that those students weren't taught clearly what is a "way to tile" then. Anyway if I read your comment literally it would be literally zero because there isn't a $0 \times 1$ square. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (d), [OEIS A000930](https://oeis.org/A000930) delights in the name of **Narayana's cows sequence**.

Starting with $n=0$:
$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19, 28, 41, 60, 88, 129, 189, 277, 406, 595, 872, 1278, 1873, 2745$

Comment: I just watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtR5XsduVMY

Comment: @VividD - hilarious