# Number of Ways To Arrange Blocks

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to pave a 1x7 rectangle by 1x1, 1x2, 1x3 blocks, assuming that blocks of the same size are indistinguishable.

[Actual Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JciRK.png)

My Attempts:

I tackled the problem in this way. I thought about the number of ways to partition the number 7 into 1's, 2's and 3's. But manually counting all of them and then permuting was turning out to be tedious. So is there a quicker more systematic way?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to list all the possibilities if you do it systematically. First find the number of ways to do it with just 3 tiles. There are only two ways of doing this: $$3+3+1\\3+2+2$$Each of these has 3 possible permutations. Then work on if you have 4 tiles, then 5 then 6 and finally 7.

Comment: No other way then. Okay well thanks for the response and for teaching me how to post a question properly.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if there is another way - there might be. That's why I didn't post it as an answer, but rather as a comment. Perhaps someone will spot a quicker method. The method I showed it just the first way I'd approach the problem if it was given to me.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272121/covering-a-rectangle-of-size-n-times1-with-dominos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways of paving a $1\times n$ rectangle with $1\times1$, $1\times2$, and $1\times3$ blocks. Then $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ for $n\ge3$. This recurrence makes it easy to find $a_4,a_5,a_6$ and then $a_7$.

Comment: Are you trying to say a0 = 1, a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 1+1+2 = 4,  a4 = 7, a5 = 13, a6 = 24 AND a7 = 44.

Comment: Those calculations are correct deductions from what I have written.

Comment: Well the answer is correct though i cant understand how it works.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: an=an−1 + an−2+ an−3.

Comment: also can i use mathjax in comments???

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) use MathJax in comments. Every paving of a $1\times n$ is either a paving of a $1\times(n-1)$ with a $1\times1$ stuck on the end, or a paving of a $1\times(n-2)$ with a $1\times2$ stuck on the end, or a paving of a $1\times(n-3)$ with a $1\times3$ stuck on the end.

Comment: Okay...THANKS a bunch.